# DNS Zones not working after OS X 10.8.5 upgrade

Tags: macos, network, dns

Prior to upgrading from OS X 10.8.4 to 10.8.5, I had the following DNS zone file in place that worked perfectly fine - now it's failing:

```
;
; BIND data file for dev sites
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     dev. root.devcs1. (
                     2013092058         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      devcs1.
@       IN      A       10.10.4.15
*.dev.  14400   IN      A       10.10.4.15
```

And by "failing" I mean that when I try to ping foo.dev, I get:

```
Cannot resolve foo.dev: Unknown host
```

"nslookup foo.dev localhost" returns:

```
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 127.0.0.1, trying next server
```

What can I do to get this zone working again? I'm trying to figure out what's changed in OS X 10.8.5, but has anyone else run into this yet? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah... I figured it out...

"named-checkconf -z" returns

```
zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 42
zone 0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1997022700
dns_rdata_fromtext: dev.zone:5: near '090712070736': out of range
zone dev/IN: loading from master file devcs1.zone failed: out of range
zone dev/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/dev/IN: out of range
```

Evidently my serial number is invalid... it should be YYYYMMDDNN (where NN is any number between 00 and 99). I changed the serial to "2013092001" and it's working fine.

Evidently the new version of Bind is more strict about serial numbers than the previous version.

You can use the following to tell what version of bind you're running:

```
nslookup -q=txt -class=CHAOS version.bind. 0
```

OS X 10.8.5 ships with Bind 9.8.5-P1.

OS X 10.8.4 shipped with 9.8.3-P1

Hopefully that helps someone else down the road.